# Is it possible to use the new Push Notifications support in Chrome without GCM?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, web-push, push-api

Can I use a push service other than Google's [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) when using the new Push API with service workers?

Comment: No, each browser uses its manufacturer's web service. If you don't want to  interact directly with GCM you can use services like [this](https://pushpad.xyz) (that will interact with GCM on your behalf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today, Chrome is the only browser that supports the standard push API so right now the short answer is No.

A longer answer involves doing different things for different browsers

- Safari offers desktop notifications via [APNS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013225-CH3-SW1) and a proprietary API
- Firefox is shipping support for push notifications [soon](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/11/17/extending-the-webs-capabilities-in-firefox-and-beyond/) and presumably will use a different push server than GCM.

So to summarize, it seems that different combinations of Browser/OS will require different push servers. In the future there is an IETF draft (https://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/webpush/documents/) that should mitigate this. There are also companies working on abstracting these problems for a fee. Just search for web push notifications to get a few of them.

Comment: Firefox nightly now has support for push and it supports the web push protocol. Hopefully Chrome will move over to supporting the web push protocol at a later date.