# Can Service Worker push notification without gcm in chrome ?

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker

Google's service include GCM can not access in my country.Can Service Worker push notification without gcm in chrome? Or if some hack technique can implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome now also uses [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) as its Push Service, which may be available in your country. You could also use a third party Push Notification platform. These would still need to access GCM or FCM but they might have some ways to get access in restricted areas. Just do a search for "push notification third party" to get a list of them.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687298/how-to-send-push-notification-to-web-browser) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838004/is-it-possible-to-use-the-new-push-notifications-support-in-chrome-without-gcm) one for more information. Be aware they are outdated, but the concepts are the same.

Comment: As far as I know,when ServiceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe chrome will subscribe a google service like "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send/xxxx",it seems like a default push server in chrome.So can we change it? if not,can we use "push notification third party"? Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: As addition,both FCM and GCM are not available in our country. In fact ,we can not use most of  google service.I found that ServiceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe promise will be always 'pending' status.